# Is there an R package designed to find balanced stimulus lists?

Tags: r, experiment-design, matching

Let's say I have two lists of 100 items.  I want to select 50 items from each list that are as similar as possible on several variables.  Is there an `R` package that can do this?

So far I've come across:

- [`LexOPS`](https://github.com/JackEdTaylor/LexOPS) which comes close, but it creates pairs of matches which is a bit too stringent for what I need;
- [`optmatch`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=optmatch) which I believe does the same.

To be clear on why these don't work: I don't need there to be matched pairs of items across the lists, only for their average values on certain variables to be similar (i.e., not significantly different), and having the extra goal of needing pairs of items makes it harder to find groups that are simply similar on average.

Comment: I don't know of such an R package, and it's really not a statistical problem, but rather an optimization one... So on the one hand, the community here (and R in general) may not be the best place to ask/do this, but other places like OR.SE will likely not be able to provide you with an R package. Anyway, have you tried a simple greedy approach (start with random lists, then swap items out and in so the means of the groups get closer together; do this multiple times with different random starts)?

Comment: Questions that are only about software (e.g. error messages, code or packages, etc.)
are generally off topic here. If you have a substantive machine learning or
statistical question, please edit to clarify.

Comment: I disagree with Stephen here.  Whilst this is an optimisation problem, it is part of the design of experiments, so I think we can reasonably classify it as being within the field of statistics.  (Maximum likelihood estimation is also an optimisation problem.)  But yes, it is true that it is a software question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you want the `bmatch()` function in the `designmatch` package, which implements mixed integer programming matching. It does not minimize a measure of imbalance; you set imbalance constraints, and it finds the sample that satisfies those constraints, if any. For example, you could require that in the two samples, the proportion of blue items in one group is within 1% of that in the other group. If your constraints are too tight, a solution will not be found, and you can try to relax the constraints until one is found. You can supply an argument to the `total_groups` parameter to control how many units are to be drawn from each list, or you can let the optimization find the largest matched sample that satisfies your constraints (this is called cardinality matching).

Comment: Sounds like exactly what I'm looking for, thanks!